# How to increment selector value at end of row in jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops, auto-increment

I have a a problem where I need to adjust the height of a parent div to the length of the longest text in a child div, but I need to test all div's in a row and find the longest text and use that width as the value for all parent divs height in that row. Then I need that same looping function to increment the jQuery selector which starts out selecting a class name "row-1" to the next row i.e row-2 and then loop through all those and set their heights ...then on to the third row, row-3 and so on till all rows returned by the server side query are tested and their row heights adjusted. Sounds strange but what it will look like is this:

http://ccs.btcny.net/redhook/

I'm using PHP to create the rows and add class names and i have a function that will output the markup cleanly and fast!

but in case this helps the PHP and overall logic is as follows:

Start with 1 item in the first row, then add 1 item to each row as you loop through the query until all items have been retrieved. and then scale everything down as the new rows are created.

I had this jquery function below running on a row by row basis...but I need one looping function till all items have been retrieved. Here is what I was able to accomplish:

```
$('.row-1 div.article-list-title').each(function() {
            maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width();

            var titwidth = $(this).width();
            console.log(titwidth);
            });

        $('.row-1').each(function() {
              $(this).height(maxWidth);
            });
$('.row-2 div.article-list-title').each(function() {
            maxWidth = maxWidth > $(this).width() ? maxWidth : $(this).width();

            var titwidth = $(this).width();
            console.log(titwidth);
            });

        $('.row-2').each(function() {
              $(this).height(maxWidth);
            });

/* And so on */
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: Could you supply some HTML code so I can play around with it. It's not very complicated to do but it would save me time if I had the HTML in a fiddle.

Comment: I can do better than that.....I have this fiddle already setup: http://jsfiddle.net/fshequin/s2jgf/127/ It does however have some other code that is outside of the problem I've asked to solve...look it over and let me know what you think! Thank you!

Comment: I actually may have solved my problem....? Not sure...but I goofed up and set the title div height to it's longest text and I'm getting the results I wanted....but please look it over and let me know what you think...I'm sure I've got extra code in there that is not needed and I've got variables reporting to the console so I can see the numeric results...they'll be stripped from final code.

Comment: Well I'm quite confused. I've checked your code and nowhere are you checking for the longest text. Well you do have the maxWidth variable, but you're not using it anywhere. Basically, all that you're doing is setting the height to 7/10 of the width (which is set through CSS). Am I missing something or did you simplify your problem!? :)

Comment: What you have now, basically comes down to this: http://jsfiddle.net/s2jgf/132/

Comment: I hate to say it but what you appear to describe is old fashioned HTML table behaviour where every cell in a row is determined by the height of the highest cell. Getting javascript to emulate table behaviour is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. If I've read the question correctly then the simplest solution is to build an appropriately styled table, or maybe a set of abutting tables of the same width.

Comment: @ComputerArts I checked the code it is actually measuring the width of the text block and applying it to the div height.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot You may have something there...I had become so anti table I might not have realized that that is the best solution...I wanted to do it in purely CSS without tables but maybe that is the direction to take? Dunno will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I know enough about what you are trying to do with this, so I'll save the "I wouldn't do it this way" speech.

Nevertheless, I think this will give you what you want (if it is jQuery you want to use).

```
heights = new array();
/** Loop through the title classes **/
$('div.article-list-title').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
    currentRow = $this.parent(),
    x = 1;
  /** Match the parent row class name **/ 
  while(! currentRow.hasClass("row-"+ x)) x++;
  if (heights.length < x) heights[x] = 0;
  if ($this.width() > heights[x]) heights[x] = $this.width();
});
/** Now update all the row-x class heights **/
for (var y = 1; y <= heights.length; y++) {
  $(".row-"+y).height(heights[y]);
}
```

Be careful with `while(! currentRow.hasClass("row-"+ x)) x++;`, should the `article-list-title` element not have a parent `row-x` class'd element it will loop forever and ever

Comment: How would you do it...I'm not afraid of that and I'm not convinced I'm doing it right..love to here what you think please!

Comment: I may not have implemented correctly but I was not able to get the above code to work.